# Excel: Create unique rows for data sampled over time

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains data that were measured over a period of 14 years. All 14 measurement periods are displayed on the same row, but I would like to have an individual row for each sampling period:

```
Unit 2001    2002    2003    2004
A.....1.0.....2.3....3.4......4.3
B.....1.2.....NA.....NA.......NA
C.....0.8.....2.3....NA.......NA
D.....NA......NA.....1.2......3.4
```

I would like to have a separate row for each sampling period, but only when it was actually sampled. The idea is so that each year and corresponding measurement will be it's own data point without including years where the unit was not sampled:

```
Unit Year Measure
A....2001...1.0
A....2002...2.3
A....2003...3.4
A....2004...4.3
B....2001...1.2
C....2001...0.8
C....2002...2.3
D....2003...1.2
D....2004...3.4
```

Is this possible to do with VBA or a formula? I'm dealing with a fairly large spreadsheet and don't want to reenter all this by hand. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a reverse pivot table on the data. You need to start the Pivot Table Wizard to do that. It is not in the ribbon, so if you have Excel 2007 or later, you must start it with a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>.

- In Step 1 tick the option **Multiple consolidation ranges** and click <kbd>Next</kbd>
- In Step 2a tick "**I will create the page fields**"
- Select the data table in Step 2b, including headers and click <kbd>Add</kbd>, then <kbd>Next</kbd>
- in Step 3 click <kbd>Finish</kbd>. Now you see a pivot table in a new worksheet. Drag the Row and the Column field out of the pivot table build tool (or untick them in the Pivot Field List), so that only one field remains: the total count and its label.
- Double-click that number
- a data source will be created on a new sheet.

[image]

Your original data will stay unchanged, so you can repeat the process at any time.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I also had multiple fields that needed to carry over so I concatenated them into one column separated by semicolons and used the "text to columns" feature after the reverse pivot table. Thanks.